# Subversion pre-commit locale

Tags: svn, localization, pre-commit-hook

How to locate from what country the commit is executed?

Example (pre-commit-hook):

```
#!/bin/sh
svnlook changed -t $2 $1 && echo && svnlook log -t $2 $1
```

Gives me ...

```
U    test/read.me
U    test/pom.xml

ABC-123: Added text to read.me and updated <name> in pom.xml
```

... in the hook. But how to locate the commit? In this example the commit has been executed from **germany**. How to add this information into the hook?

Comment: What is the actual requirement you're attempting to fulfill?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible. The committing IP is not made available to hook scripts. Even if it were, geolocation by IP address is not reliable due to VPNs, NAT, proxies, etc. With the free VPN service I have on my computer right now I can make myself appear to be in any one of 18 or so countries around the world with a single mouse click.

Additionally, your hook script should not be attempting to modify the in-flight commit to begin with (if that's what you're looking to do).

You could configure a pre-commit hook to require that a location be included in the text of the commit message and reject if it's not, but you'd have to standardize how those locations are formatted and anytime a new (legitimate) location was used, you'd have to update your hook script (or set up a database to perform a lookup, and maintain that database).

There are *probably* better ways to achieve whatever you're attempting to do, but you haven't provided enough detail about your requirements to really say.